# How do I stop a child component from re-rendering when its parent reloads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code with the countdown npm library

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Panel, Button } from 'rsuite';
import Countdown from 'react-countdown-now';
export default class GamePlay extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            select: false
        }
        this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    }
    onSelect(e){
        this.setState({ select: e.target.name });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-6 offset-3">
                    <Panel className="text-center bg-white" header={<h3>Question</h3>} bordered>
                        <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                            Time left: 
                            <Countdown date={Date.now() + 30000} />
                        </div>
                    </Panel>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5">
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div className="col-6">
                            <Button name="A" appearance={`${this.state.select === 'A' ? 'primary': 'default'}`} block onClick={this.onSelect} bordered>A</Button>
                            <Button name="C" appearance={`${this.state.select === 'C' ? 'primary' : 'default'}`} block onClick={this.onSelect} bordered>C</Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-6">
                            <Button name="B" appearance={`${this.state.select === 'B' ? 'primary' : 'default'}`} block onClick={this.onSelect} bordered>B</Button>
                            <Button name="D" appearance={`${this.state.select === 'D' ? 'primary' : 'default'}`} block onClick={this.onSelect} bordered>D</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I click on a button to select an answer it causes the GamePlay component to re-render, and therefore the countdown is restarted.

How do I stop it from restarting when I click on an answer? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You should remove all state logic from the render function(). The only purpose of render() is to turn component state into HTML, it's not supposed to do anything beyond that. Put stuff like initializing values into `componentDidMount()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can defined the `date` property value outside the render function so it won't change when the parent is re-rendered.

Here is an example:

```
constructor(){
  ....
  this.date = Date.now() + 30000;
}

render(){
  ....
  <Countdown date={this.date} />
  ....
}
```